# How can I restore System.Data and other files missing from Windows\Microsoft.NET Folder, not restored by repair tool or turning features off and on?

Tags: .net, powershell, missing-data, gac, system.data

Powershell:

> Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Data, Version =4.0.0.0.
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089’ or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I was able to fix the immediate problem by copying System.Data from another computer, but in the process I discovered that many other files are missing from my Microsoft.NET Folder.

I tried the repair tool, and turning the NET Framework features off and on, before copying System.Data from another computer, but neither of those restored System.Data, and there are still many files missing from my Microsoft.NET Folder.

Does anyone have any other ideas for me to try, to restore the missing files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
This is a forum where coders voluntarily help other coders with their challenges. ;-) There are some rules and best practices helping you to get the most out of SO. 
First you may take the [Tour] to get an overview and then you may stop by on [ask]. 
To make it easier for others willing to help you to actually help you you should always [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly and provide a [mre].  And BTW: You did not ask any question!? 
 ;-) Have a nice day!

Comment: Don't put SOLVED in the title. If you have a solution, post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of searching and only finding two examples of files missing from the Microsoft.NET folder on the user side, and not finding any examples where the files were restored without a clean install of Windows, I'm thinking that in most cases that would be the only solution, if the files aren't restored by DISM and sfc.